# Sql with mysql reserved word

Tags: php, mysql, reserved-words, reserved

I have this following sql code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO data (Artist, Name) VALUES ('TF2', 'you're right behind me')";
```

The code itself looks normal but for some reason mysql doesn't want to allow me to save it. I get the following error:

```
"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 're right behind me')' at line 1"
```

What I know the problem is because of the word "right" being reserved in mysql but I need to save it so how should my code look like. All help is appreciated

Comment: I believe that is because of extra single qoute `'you're right behind me'` in `you're`. Maybe you can escape it by using backslash?

Comment: You need to escape your commas. Use `You\'re` for instance. There's a function for that, called `addslashes`. Consult the PHP manual on the matter http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Comment: this is a good argument for parameterized queries

Comment: @Fred addaslashes is **NOT** the function that should be used to escape sql parameters. Each db library has it's own function that will take into account things such as the encoding of the connection to properly escape the string (mysql_escape_string, mysqli_real_escape_string, etc). Even better, would be using bound parameters so you don't have to escape them manually.

Comment: @jcsanyi You're right. I was 50% right, apostrophes need to be escaped, if manually inserted. ;-)

Comment: I meant `mysql_real_escape_string` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php - I looked up the wrong function.

Comment: Okay, have used mysql_real_escape_string like two years ago, forgot about if that was the one. Thanks Fred and @jcsanyi

Comment: @AmandaWood You're welcome, hope this solved your problem Amanda.

Comment: @AmandaWood You haven't mentioned what libraries you are using to actually connect to mysql. If you're using mysql_connect, mysql_query, etc, then yes - mysql_escape_string() is what you want. If you're using mysqli or PDO, there's corresponding functions that you should use with them instead.

Comment: @AmandaWood If you **are** using the mysql_* functions, **[please reconsider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).**  They are no longer maintained and are officially deprecated. See the **[red box](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)**? You can use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) instead - [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) can help you decide which to use.

Comment: @Dukeling: Not really, it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Fred and @JunM have already commented, you have two issues. The first is that Name is a reserved word. The second is that you have a single quote inside your single quoted string. Change your SQL to this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO data (`Artist`, `Name`) VALUES ('TF2', 'you\'re right behind me')";
```

Comment: This works for this particular exempel, but the thing is the name is submitted by user, and are different from time to time, is there any permament solution?

Comment: @AmandaWood http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Comment: @AmandaWood `addslashes()` is **not** what you should be using. See my comment above

Comment: @AmandaWood He's right. I looked up the wrong function. See `jcsanyi's` comment above.

Comment: @jcsanyi I stand corrected.

Comment: @Fred Okay, should I be using mysql_escape_string?

Comment: @AmandaWood I would say yes, however I'm not an MySQL expert. Views on this anyone? There are examples on the PHP.net link I gave you.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because you have an `'` in the work `you're`. So your string is terminating to early in your sentence.  Use `you\'re` instead to escape the character `'`

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO data ('Artist', 'Name') VALUES ('TF2', 'you\'re right behind me')";
```

Answer (score 0):

My experience with MySQL is limited, but I use SQL Server extensively. To me it seems that the problem is in the apostrophy used in the "you're right behind me". In SQL server, I'd have to use a double apostrophy, so the sql instruction would be something like this (notice the double apostrophy in the you''re):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO data (Artist, Name) VALUES ('TF2', 'you''re right behind me')";
```

Hope this helps.
Regards

Comment: This is wrong, you have to escape ' with \'

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @ObieMD5. I use the double quotes in SQL Server. Regards

Comment: yet another argument for parameterized queries... escaping is done in a database specific way.